# Using Kalman filter for high-dimensional observation

Tags: kalman-filters

My observation space is essentially a noisy high-resolution video. In this case, regular Kalman filter doesn't work because the covariance matrix is of size (pixel x pixel) and just doesn't fit in memory. What is the typical solution in this case?

Comment: What would you like to track with the Kalman?

Comment: @NirRegev a low dimensional latent process well modeled with an autoregressive process.